Refresh indicator removed too early
The issue is when i use a Future.delayed of 10 seconds then return a future.value the refresh indicator behaves correcty, spinning for 10 seconds then it is removed, but when i change it to use my method it fails, and instead spins for 1 second without waiting for my future to return.
Widget snippet housing refresh indicator
RefreshIndicator(
                  key: refreshIndicatorKey,
                  onRefresh: () {
                    if (isLoading == false) {
                      final completer = Completer<void>();

                      retryFunction().then((_) {
                        completer.complete();
                      });

  //This works as expected
                          // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
                          //   completer.complete();
                          // });


                      return completer.future;
                    } else {
                      return Future.value();
                    }
                  },
                  child: child);

The call back (retryFunction)
Future<void> initializations({bool refetchPosts = false}) async {

//When i change it to this it also works correctly.
//await Future.delayed(seconds: 10);

    await ref
        .read(singlePostProvider.notifier)
        .fetchSinglePostInfo(widget.safePostModel.id!);
  }

i put a break point at completer.complete() and yes the break point is not reached for about 4 seconds, but still the refresh indicator stops showing even though the future has not completed.
this is the provider function
Future<void> fetchSinglePostInfo(String id) async {
    try {
      state = BaseState.loading(data: state.data);
      return await safeRepo.fetchPostDetails(id).then((value) {
        state = BaseState.success(
            SafePostModel.fromJson(value["data"]["formattedPost"]));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      state = BaseState.error(e.toString(), data: state.data);
    }
  }


Did you try this?
  onRefresh: () async {
                    if (isLoading == false) {
                      final completer = Completer<void>();

                      await retryFunction();
                      await completer.complete();
        

